# Problem with noun phrase

Tags: clauses

My question is if phrase "me to have my job" is noun phrase ?

Here is the example:

The reason for me to have my job is that I keep secret.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "The reason for me to have my job is that I keep secret." And no, it's not a noun phrase.

Comment: I mean : The reason for me to keep my job is that I keep secret about what I do.

Comment: The whole phrase is not a noun phrase but it contains a noun phrase.  See http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/nounphrase.htm for an explanation.

Comment: BTW, *secrets* or *a secret*. Also more natural might be "can keep" as you are describing a capability (I *am able to* keep a secret).

Comment: The example is not grammatical, and I'm not sure what it should mean when corrected. It might mean either: "The reason that I have my job is that I am able to keep secrets" or, a different meaning entirely: "The reason for me to have my job is to help me keep my secret." James Bond is chosen to be a spy because he is able to keep secrets; Spider-Man is motivated to be a photographer because it helps him keep his secret identity.